# Laravel get model by hasManyThrough

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have 3 classes - User, Business and BusinessRoleUser (and respective tables)

> (user) id | first_name | last_name
>
> (business) business_id | business_name
>
> (business_role_user) user_id | business_id | role_id

I have combined the role of the user in the same table as their are multiple roles that user's can have towards a business i.e. admin, staff, etc. which are in the business_roles table.

I would like to access the Business Model through a logged in User to update fields i.e.

```
$business = User::find(Auth::id())->business();

$business->fill(Input::all());
$business->save();
```

At present in my User class I have the following (really each user will only be associated to one business):

```
public function business()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Business', 'App\BusinessRoleUser', 'business_id', 'user_id');
    }
```

But If I do a simple `dd(User::find(Auth::id())->business->business_name);`

it throws an error

> business name is undefined

It's not actually finding the business model associated to the user. I've looked at many examples of hasManyThrough but am failing to get this to work, appreciate the help!

*(note user table uses id where as other tables use user_id, not sure if this is causing an issue)*

Comment: hope you understand the concept of hasManyThrough? am sure the issue is coming from the relationship definition

Comment: Hi, I'm relatively new to all this, but assume I'm somehow able to access the business model from the logged in user? and Vice versa i.e. grab users through my business model as well through my business_role_user table (perhaps this is only where hasManyThrough applies)? Sorry are you able to elaborate if I'm going about this wrong and point me in the right direction? I can't add a user_id to my business table as a business can have multiple users and multiple users may access a business. The alternate is I just make a function under users to get the business id and then do a Business::where..

Comment: I think you can use many to many relationship. Try this: `public function business()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\BusinessRoleUser', 'App\Business', 'user_id', 'role_id')->withPivot([ array of fields you want from business table ]);
}`

Comment: if the code above doesn't work you can use to it to figure it out. am trying to re-create your issue and see get a solution

Comment: `public function business() { return $this->belongsToMany('App\Business', 'business_role_user', 'user_id', 'business_id'); }` works by then simply using `User::find(Auth::id())->business->first();` I now understand your first comment re. relationship definition - thank you!!

Comment: glad it worked. I will provide my comment as answer please accept.